# Setting the checkbox checked value(the initial) as true in the grid view make a strange behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview, checkbox

I face a strange behavior when i make the default for check box in the gridview is `Checked = true` !!

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnl_lect" runat="server">
     <asp:GridView ID="gv_lect" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="prog_ser,lect_code,lect_type"
                        CssClass="formTable cr_center" OnDataBound="gv_lect_DataBound" OnRowDataBound="gv_lect_RowDataBound">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="lect_name" DataField="name" />
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="1">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_1" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="2">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_2" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="3">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_3" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="4">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_4" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="5">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_5" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="6">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_6" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="7">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_7" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="8">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_8" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="9">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_9" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="10">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_10" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="11">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_11" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="12">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_12" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="13">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_13" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="14">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_14" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="15">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_15" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="16">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_16" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="17">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_17" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="18">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_18" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="19">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_19" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="20">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox_20" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView> 
  </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

---

```
 protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool res = true;
            try
            {

                CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)sender;

                GridViewRow r = (GridViewRow)chkbox.NamingContainer;
                ProgAbsence abs = new ProgAbsence();

                int progSer = int.Parse(((GridView)(r.NamingContainer)).DataKeys[r.DataItemIndex].Values[0].ToString());
                int lectCode = int.Parse(((GridView)(r.NamingContainer)).DataKeys[r.DataItemIndex].Values[1].ToString());
                int lectType = int.Parse(((GridView)(r.NamingContainer)).DataKeys[r.DataItemIndex].Values[2].ToString());
                int sessionId = int.Parse(chkbox.ID.Split('_')[1]);
                abs.LectCode = lectCode;
                abs.LectType = lectType;
                abs.ProgSer = progSer;
                abs.SessionId = sessionId;
                if (chkbox.Checked)
                {
                    res = abs.Add();
                }
                else
                {
                    res = abs.Delete();
                }
                BindAbsence();
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                res = false;
                BindAbsence();
            }
        }
        /* =========================================================================== */
        protected void gv_lect_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.DataItemIndex >= 0)
            {


                DataTable dt = ((DataTable)ViewState["abs"]);
                if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (((GridView)(e.Row.NamingContainer)).DataKeys[e.Row.DataItemIndex].Values[0].ToString().Trim() == dt.Rows[i]["prog_ser"].ToString()
                            &&
                            ((GridView)(e.Row.NamingContainer)).DataKeys[e.Row.DataItemIndex].Values[1].ToString().Trim() == dt.Rows[i]["lect_code"].ToString()
                            &&
                            ((GridView)(e.Row.NamingContainer)).DataKeys[e.Row.DataItemIndex].Values[2].ToString().Trim() == dt.Rows[i]["lect_type"].ToString())
                        {
                            ((CheckBox)(e.Row.Cells[int.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["session_id"].ToString())].Controls[1])).Checked = true;
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        /* =========================================================================== */
```

This code works fine but when i make all the check boxes checked property default value is `true` instead of `false` , i get wrong checkbox(not the sender) and the event works sometimes not all the time !!
How to make the checkbox default value is true and make it works as expected ?

Comment: Why do you expect an error? Have you at least set a breakpoint in the `catch`? Do you get an exception?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: i have already tried it .
`CheckBox chkbox = (CheckBox)sender;` the checkbox id is n't the one which i clicked and sometimes i feel like it stuck the check doesn't change!

Comment: Did you make the default value=true in c# or in the aspx page?

Comment: @Koen :in the aspx page

Comment: and does only 1 (wrong)checkbox send a postback? or do they all when you click 1?

Comment: Two problem :
1-the check box is n't the right one i click
2-some checkboxes the checked fired twice checked and unchecked like it stuck

Comment: Is it in an `UpdatePanel`? Do you have any javascript on the page you are not showing? I think we need to see more.

Comment: @DavidG:yes,it's in the `updatepanel`

Comment: @just_name Please minimize the checkboxes to one or two, as they  have the same behavior and add the markup code for the updatepanel and its triggers. Please also read through the first point of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm tried to replicate your case everything working fine for me. I took Your GridView code and put it in updatePanel and tried. Can you show us updatepanel and triggers if you have or any client side javascript code

Answer (score 2):

Did you set `EnableViewState` to `false` in the Page directive or in a control containing your GridView?

```
<%@ Page EnableViewState="false" ... %>
```

The [CheckBox.CheckedChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) might not work properly without this set to `true`.  MSDN says:

> A CheckBox control must persist some values between posts to the server for this event to work correctly. Be sure that view state is enabled for this control.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly test the said scenario in the new solution and instead of binding the gridview from database, try to bind it using defined data(DataTable with values). and From there implement your code piece by piece.

Comment: Got a negative feedback :(... I don't have enough reputation to do a comment. I was trying to help him...

I guess my suggestion is also part of this 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @just_name, kindly re-build your project or specific scenario in the new solution. I actually tried your scenario in my local and haven't encountered what you said. Probably one of the your code on databound or something causes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is checklist you should go thuru on this list..**

1. Make sure you enabled `ViewState` on page
2. You are using update panel so make Children As Trigger property to `true`
3. Make sure `AutoPostBack=true`
4. If you binding your Gridview on `Page_load` Put Binding in  `if(!IsnotPostBack) {}`
5. Make sure you not check or made change on checkbox using `javascript` 
   If you still have a problem create new page and try with only `grid-view` It might be other issue..